# Father being Matir Neder for himself: does it affect the family?

Tags: halacha, minhag, minor-katan-child, family-members, nedarim-shevuot

If a father is Matir Neder on a minhag (gebroktz, let's say) for himself for a valid reason, does that include his whole family? Are they now also permitted to eat gebroktz because that is now the father's minhag? Would there be a difference between his son who is bar mitzvah and one who is not bar mitzvah (still under the father's rule)?

Comment: How is this different from if the father took on a new minhag? I don't see why that would be binding on others, certainly not on sons over bar mitzva!

Comment: @DoubleAA ,diff is the minhag is from grandfather if the father has to break the minhag I understand,but the son whos real minhag is from his grandfather does it switch or stay the same. Do youhave any sources?

Comment: (I don't know why you say the grandfather's minhag is the _real_ one.) So the cases are parallel. Using your example: If I accept gebrochts, should my son over bar mitzva have to start keeping it when his grandfather didn't and he never did growing up? No source, but seems highly unlikely.

Comment: What does his wife do? Just trying to get some sources to work it out.

Comment: @sam His wife probably follows his new minhag. Because a reason given for a woman to switch to her husband's mi'hagim is, because she is like ההולך ממקום למקום ואין דעתו לחזור . And consider also that a husband can generally be meifer (even in this case, maybe this is not ביום שמעו ?..?). Anyway, intersting question! +1

Comment: How can someone be matir neder on himself?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Minhag is one for which Hatarah can work, the father may represent his family as he and they are all equally part of the Minhag and all equally require Hatarah thereby sidestepping the problem of Shlichus for Hatarah, though it's really best if all those above 12/11 (those below 12/11 don't have any obligation in Nedarim yet anyway) who wish to be included in the Hatarah write and sign a document expressing their Charatah. This is based on Shu"T Chasam Sofer YD 220. See also Shu"T Harei Besamim (Horwitz) I 44 who disagrees. However, it must be stated that it is not necessarily so clear cut that Hataras Nedarim is appropriate and will work for a Minhag like not eating Sh'ruyah (Gebrokts) on Pesach...